# Sharepoint security trim control for hiding share button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My requirement is to hide the `spsharepromotedActionButton` control from the ribbon. This control generate the share button for list item in the ribbon. We are using bootstrap master page.

I know couple of options available.

1. using CSS
2. using security trim control.

Which option is best. Any details, code example for both scenario would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no best option.
If you would like to hide the control for all users, then using css is the simple solution.
If you allow some people to see the control while others shall not see, then security trimmed control will do.